Add copy to clipboard button in Quarto dashboard
I would like to add a button which copies the input or output of a user in a Quarto dashboard. I found the shiny2clipboard which seems a good option. Unfortunately, the code I'm trying to run doesn't copy the text to the clipboard inside a Quarto dashboard. When you run the example code from the blog in the link it does work but not in a Quarto dashboard. Here is some reproducible code:
---
title: "Test"
format: dashboard
server: shiny
---

## Test

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(shinyCopy2clipboard)
```

```{r}
#| title: "Text that needs to copy to clipboard"

# Setup
  use_copy()

  # Text Input 1
  textInput("text", "Enter Your Text")

  # Copy Button 1
shinyCopy2clipboard::CopyButton(
    "copybtn",
    label = "Copy to clipboard",
    icon = icon("copy"),
    text = "No Text Found"
  )
```


```{r}
#| context: server
observe({

    req(input$copybtn)
  shinyCopy2clipboard::CopyButtonUpdate(session,
                     id = "copybtn",
                     label = "Copy to clipboard",
                     icon = icon("copy"),
                     text = input$text
    )

  })
```

Output:

As you can see in the output I try to copy the text from the input field to my clipboard. This doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a button to copy text to your clipboard inside a Quarto dashboard?

Interesting. You don't need a package to do this in Shiny. I'm not sure if the Quarto dashboard API has the same JS custom message handler as Shiny but I'd be surprised if it didn't have something similar. See here for how to use this to copy text to clipboard with standard Shiny: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78448126/copying-output-to-clipboard-in-r-shiny

@SamR, thank you for your comment! I saw your beautiful answer, but I’m not sure how to implement this to a Quarto dashboard. Mainly the tags$script part.

You can define an actionButton which has an onclick event. There, we read the current text from the textInput (using txt = document.getElementById('text').value;) and then pass this to the clipboard with navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt);:
---
title: "Test"
format: dashboard
server: shiny
---

## Test

```{r}
library(shiny)
```

```{r}
#| title: "Text that needs to copy to clipboard"

# Text Input 1
textInput("text", "Enter Your Text")

actionButton(
  "copy_link", 
  "Copy to clipboard", 
  onclick = "
    txt = document.getElementById('text').value;
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(txt);"
)
```

```{r}
#| context: server
```



Thank you for your answer! This works nice. May I ask if we replace textInput with verbatimTextOutput, can we do it in a similar way?

Sure. What exactly do you would like to do? Do you want to copy what is displayed inside a verbatimTextOutput into the clipboard? If so, you could e.g. use document.getElementById('verb').textContent, if the verbatimTextOutput has outputId = 'verb'.
